# How to edit the account results in the leads object?

Tags: lightning, lead-conversion, object, edit

In the leads object, when I click on "Convert" a lead, I click on "choose existing", I want to search for an account, then I can see a page with Account results (as you can see in the picture). [image] [image]

I would like to know if it's possible to edit the Account Results by replacing the Phone column with another.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - this is easily done by going to `Setup > Object Manager > Account` and then `Search Layouts`.

These can be customized by Profile - See [Customize Search Layouts](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customizing_search_layouts.htm&type=5)

Comment: Thank you I found it!!

Comment: As a service to the community and if the answer did in fact solve your issue; it is best practice to mark as accepted.  This way others searching on the same topic can rely on the answer